# How to filter by tag in Silverstripe, when using tagfield module?

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have the following page type in Silverstripe which has many CategoryTags. CategoryTag is a dataobject created with silverstripe-tagfield module.

```
class ArticlePage extends Page {
 ...
  private static $many_many = array(
            'CategoryTags' => 'CategoryTag'
        );
...
```

I want to return all other ArticlePages that have matching CategoryTags to the current page. I know I can return all other ArticlePages and filter them, like:

```
public function getRelatedArticles() {
            $relatedArticles = ArticlePage::get()->filter(SOME FILTER);
             return ($relatedArticles);
         }
```

But I'm unsure of the syntax to filter by the current page's CategoryTags . How would I adjust the above function to achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After quite a lot of head scratching, I found a solution:

```
 public function getRelatedArticles(){
    return ArticlePage::get()->filter('CategoryTags.ID', $this->CategoryTags()->column('ID'))->exclude('ID', $this->ID);
 }
```

Hopefully this saves someone some time in future :)